# Locks in properties

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, clr

I was wondering about the proper use of locks in properties. I am writing a multi-threaded server application, where throughput is very important. If I have a property declared like that:

```
    private DataPoint a;
    private object aLock = new object();
```

The most conservative lock seems to be the following (call it Method 1). But, in this case, on every invocation after the initial one, there will be an overhead of a lock:

```
    public DataPoint A
    {
        get
        {
            lock (aLock)
            {
                if (a == null)
                {
                    a = new DataPoint();
                }

                return a;
            }
        }
    }
```

Or, should I move the lock to just the line that sets "a" (call it Method 2). In this case, there is a possibility that "a" will be set several times (which is Ok), but once it's set, there is no overhead of a lock.

```
    public DataPoint A
    {
        get
        {
            if (a == null)
            {
                lock(aLock)
                {
                    a = new DataPoint();
                }
            }

            return a;
        }
    }
```

What is the recommended way to lock concurrent access to properties? Is it method 1, method 2 or none of the above?

Thanks.

Comment: The `lock` in the second example is completely pointless (no pun intended), but whether you should be locking at all (as opposed to just having a sensible initialization value) is a different quesiton.

Comment: Why don't you initialize your DataPoint in the class constructor?

Comment: The second example may be a valid scenario, depending on what's going on in the constructor of the DataPoint. I should have not used "new DataPoint()" for illustration purposes, but instead used something like DataPoint.Create("A")...

Comment: you are developing a server and u have locks? good luck.

Comment: The second scenario is indeed valid. You'd probably not want to lock if it has already been initialized. However, after the lock(aLock) you should (again) check a for null or else you may end up initializing multiple times if two concurrent calls to the getter are executed when a is not initialized.

Comment: @user1044169 - the reason the second example is pointless because two threads could both pass the `a==null` test before either one gets to assigning something to a. So the second thread through the lock will overwrite the first. Since that can happen, why even bother with the lock?

Comment: To avoid race conditions

Comment: @user1044169 But the second example fails in that department.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .NET 4, you have the `System.Lazy<T>` type that takes care of these issues for you:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly Lazy<DataPoint> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new DataPoint());

    public DataPoint Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
}
```

Courtesy of [Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: Note that in this particular case, a simple static readonly field would have the same effect.

Comment: @Sebastian - when and how would you initialize that field ?

Comment: As Jon Skeet points out in the same article as item 4 (or 5 for that matter), static fields are initialized on the first class access if you provide a static constructor.

Comment: @Sebastian I see. However since your comment I have altered the post to be more similar to the OP's code, and now nothing is static...

Answer (score 2):

In your example of locking, you are doing so to initialize a value. Assuming the null condition means the the value needs to be initialized, you should be checking for it before *and* after you acquire the lock:

```
if(a == null)
{
  lock(aLock)
  {
    if(a == null)
      a = new DataPoint();
  }
}
```

The reason for this is because while a thread is waiting on the lock, there's a chance that the work it is going to do once it acquires the lock is already being done by a different thread. So when the thread acquires the lock, it should check to see if the work still needs to be done.

Comment: Some people consider double check locking to be an anti-pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Actually, under the ECMA CLI memory model it may even be broken: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx (Third version)

Comment: Under the Java memory model this is definitely broken unless the reference is volatile or the DataPoint is atomically constructed – for Java this would mean that all fields are final.

Answer (score 1):

you should check for null before locking.
if it is null, then lock, and check for null again.
if it is still null, initiate your DataPoint and assign it to a temporary variable first.
when done, assign it to your member and return it.

```
private DataPoint _dataPoint;

public DataPoint A
{
    get
    {
        if(_dataPoint != null)
            return _dataPoint;

        lock (aLock)
        {
            if (_dataPoint == null)
            {
                var dataPoint = new DataPoint();
                // do more stuff with dataPoint
                _dataPoint = dataPoint;
            }

            return _dataPoint;
        }
    }
}
```